# C++ Template Array filled with random numbers

Tags: c++, arrays, object

I'm sure I could solve this eventually on my own, but I don't have much experience with C++. I am attempting to make a program that stores 10 vehicles, and their prices using objects, and arrays. One of the functions writes the input to an object, and that object is stored in the next empty spot in the array. What currently happens, is that the array fills up with random numbers after the first slot has been filled. I only want one input, for example "Honda 3500" to be in car #1, and so on. Currently, the output looks like this after inputting one car:

```
1. Add a car to inventory
2. Delete a car from inventory
3. Print inventory
4. Exit
Your choice: 1
Make of car, and price of car, separated by spaces: Honda 3500
Car Added
1. Add a car to inventory
2. Delete a car from inventory
3. Print inventory
4. Exit
Your choice: 3
Car #1: Honda 3500
Car #2:  336003091
Car #3:  -305070080
Car #4:  1715512660
Car #5:  1
Car #6:  1715214184
Car #7:  817108032
Car #8:  1707190918
Car #9:  0
Car #10:  71
```

And afterwards, if trying to add another car, the array is filled, and the for loop that searches for empty space returns false, meaning it's unable to find any empty space in the array. I removed the price from the print statement, and it looked something like this:

```
Car #1: honda
Car #2:
Car #3:
Car #4:
Car #5:
Car #7:
Car #8:
Car #9:
Car #10:
```

So I suspect it's something with the price, however, the array is still filled with random numbers, so it's not just a print error. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Here is my code:

```
int main (void) {
    array<Car, 10> carArr; 
    int input = 0;

    do{
        displayMenu();
        cin >> input;
        if (input == 1){ 
            addData(carArr);
        } else if (input == 2){ 
            deleteData(carArr);
        } else if (input == 3){
            printData(carArr);
        } else if (input == 4){
            break;
        } else {
            cout << "invalid selection" << endl;
        }
    }
    while (1);
}

void displayMenu (){
    cout << "1. Add a car to inventory\n2. Delete a car from inventory\n3. Print inventory\n4. Exit\nYour choice: ";
}

bool addData(array<Car,10>& carArr){
    Car carObj;
    cout << "Make of car, and price of car, separated by spaces: ";
    cin >> carObj.carMake >> carObj.carPrice; 
    for (int i = 0;i < 10;i++) { 
        if (carArr[i].getCarMake().compare("") == 0 ){  // if array[i].carmake is equal to ""
            carArr[i] = carObj;
            cout << "Car Added" << endl;
            return true;
        } else {
            cout << "There are no open Elements in the array" << endl;
            return false;
        }
    }
}

bool deleteData(array<Car,10>& carArr){ // this isnt finished
    return false;
    return true;
}
void printData(array<Car,10>& carArr){
    for (int i = 0;i < 10;i++) {
        cout << "Car #" << i+1 << ": " << carArr[i].getCarMake() << " " << carArr[i].getCarPrice() << endl;
    }
}
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Car {
    public:
    string carMake;
    int carPrice;

    Car (string make,int price) { // use this to set car make and car price
        carMake = make;
        carPrice = price;
    }
    Car () { //default contructor

    }
    string getCarMake () {
        return carMake;
    }
    int getCarPrice () {
        return carPrice;
    }
    void setCarMake (string x){
        carMake = x;
    }
};
```

Comment: It's unclear if you're accidentally or deliberately using a `Car`'s make as your https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern

Comment: @MooingDuck it is pretty clear that it is deliberate. It is just not being checked everywhere that is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed-length arrays don't keep track of how many slots you fill, or even have a concept of "empty" slots. You have to keep track of that yourself, such as by maintaining a separate integer to hold the number of filled slots, or by using `std::optional` for the array's element type, etc.

In your case, you are using a blank `carMake` to indicate an empty array slot, which is fine, except that your `printData()` function is ignoring that indicator, it just blindly prints out every array slot whether it has been filled or not. Your `Car`'s default constructor is not initializing the `carPrice` member (it does initialize the `carMake` member), which is why you are getting random numbers (but not random strings) for unfilled array slots.

Also, your `addData()` function has a flaw. It is exiting its loop prematurely after 1 item has been added to the array. The whole `else` block needs to be moved outside of the loop.

Try something more like this:

```
int main () {
    array<Car, 10> carArr;
    int input = 0;

    do{
        displayMenu();
        cin >> input;
        if (input == 1){ 
            addData(carArr);
        } else if (input == 2){ 
            deleteData(carArr);
        } else if (input == 3){
            printData(carArr);
        } else if (input == 4){
            break;
        } else {
            cout << "invalid selection" << endl;
        }
    }
    while (true);
}

void displayMenu (){
    cout << "1. Add a car to inventory\n"
         << "2. Delete a car from inventory\n"
         << "3. Print inventory\n"
         << "4. Exit\n"
         << "Your choice: ";
}

bool addData(array<Car,10>& carArr){
    Car carObj;
    cout << "Make of car, and price of car, separated by spaces: ";
    cin >> carObj.carMake >> carObj.carPrice; 
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) { 
        if (carArr[i].getCarMake() == ""){  // if array[i].carmake is equal to ""
            carArr[i] = carObj;
            cout << "Car Added" << endl;
            return true;
        }
    }

    cout << "There are no open Elements in the array" << endl;
    return false;
}

bool deleteData(array<Car,10>& carArr){ // this isnt finished
    return false;
}

void printData(array<Car,10>& carArr){
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        if (carArr[i].getCarMake() != ""){  // if array[i].carmake is not ""
            cout << "Car #" << ++j << ": " << carArr[i].getCarMake() << " " << carArr[i].getCarPrice() << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

That being said, consider using `std::vector` instead. It is a dynamic array that grows as needed, and its `size()` method reports the number of valid items that have been put in it:

```
int main () {
    vector<Car> carArr;
    int input = 0;

    do{
        displayMenu();
        cin >> input;
        if (input == 1){ 
            addData(carArr);
        } else if (input == 2){ 
            deleteData(carArr);
        } else if (input == 3){
            printData(carArr);
        } else if (input == 4){
            break;
        } else {
            cout << "invalid selection" << endl;
        }
    }
    while (true);
}

void displayMenu (){
    cout << "1. Add a car to inventory\n"
         << "2. Delete a car from inventory\n"
         << "3. Print inventory\n"
         << "4. Exit\n"
         << "Your choice: ";
}

bool addData(vector<Car>& carArr){
    Car carObj;
    cout << "Make of car, and price of car, separated by spaces: ";
    cin >> carObj.carMake >> carObj.carPrice;     
    carArr.push_back(carObj);
    cout << "Car Added" << endl;
    return true;
}

bool deleteData(vector<Car>& carArr){ // this isnt finished
    return false;
}

void printData(vector<Car>& carArr){
    for (size_t i = 0; i < carArr.size(); ++i) {
        cout << "Car #" << i+1 << ": " << carArr[i].getCarMake() << " " << carArr[i].getCarPrice() << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, still fairly new to the whole object thing, but I'm starting to get it. Your help has been invaluable to my progress, thank you again!!!